# Test-DscConfiguration against container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, containers, dsc

I have no problem to deploy my windows 2016 containers (base on servercore) and apply a config in push mode (for now, pull later) , but got no idea how to remotely test the status of my container (like with `test-dscconfiguration -Computer` ....) , any ideas ?

Ps : I can use `Enter-Pssession` with "-ContainerID" param and try to find a solution like that for `Test-DscConfiguration` or any good alternative ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Test-DscConfiguration -ComputerName <ContainerComputerName>`?

Comment: yes but without any success, i have an error "0x8009030e"